# Connecting with SFTP changes ownership of home directory to root:root

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, sftp, home

We are suddenly experiencing a weird issue when connecting with SFTP to our server.

The server hosts multiple home directories for multiple users, each under `/home/store/userXYZ`.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. set ownership of home directory to user:user-group (`/home/store/userXYZ`)
2. connect via sftp using the user account/credentials
3. sftp login directory defaults to the users home directory
4. ownership of the users home directory gets set to root:root on sftp login

In past times, this worked as expected and ownership of the home directory was not overridden on connecting with sftp.

We have **not** changed any config files or values regarding chroot in `sshd_config`, `# ChrootDirectory %h` is commented out, so I'm guessing that's what sshd is using by default. Login via ssh also defaults to the users home directory.

Any ideas what the issue here could be?

Thanks! :-)